# Parsing a full site using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I've created a crawler which is scraping name, phone number and web address of each profile from houzz website. Hope I did it the right way. Here is what I've written:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://www.houzz.com/professionals/"

def scraper_func(mainurl):
    response = requests.get(mainurl).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//a[@class='sidebar-item-label']"):
        link = titles.xpath(".//@href")
        for item in link:
            paging_stuff(item)

# Done crawling links to the category from left-sided bar
def paging_stuff(process_links):
    response = requests.get(process_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']"):
        link = titles.xpath(".//a[@class='pageNumber']/@href")
        for item in link:
            processing_stuff(item)

# Going to each page to crawl the whole links spread through pagination connected to the profile page
def processing_stuff(procured_links):
    response = requests.get(procured_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='name-info']"):
        links = titles.xpath(".//a[@class='pro-title']/@href")[0]
        main_stuff(links)

# Going to the profile page of each link
def main_stuff(main_links):
    response = requests.get(main_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)

    def if_exist(titles,xpath):
        info=titles.xpath(xpath)
        if info:
            return info[0]
        return ""

    for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='profile-cover']"):
        name = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='profile-full-name']/text()")
        phone = if_exist(titles,".//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' click-to-call-link ')]/@phone")
        web = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='proWebsiteLink']/@href")
        print(name,phone,web)

scraper_func(url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely [re-use the same session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) for multiple requests to the same domain - it should result into a *performance improvement*:

> if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase

**Other Improvements**

- improve *naming*: you are over reusing `item` and `titles` variables. Instead, think of more appropriate and meaningful variable names. Also, I don't think the "_stuff" prefix contributes to readability and ease of understanding of the program
- put the main script execution logic to under [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid executing it on import
- you can avoid inner loops and iterate directly over `href`s here:

  ```
  for link in tree.xpath("//a[@class='sidebar-item-label']/@href"):
      paging_stuff(link)
  ```

  And here:

  ```
  for link in tree.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//a[@class='pageNumber']/@href"):
      processing_stuff(link)
  ```
- instead of putting comments before the functions, put them into appropriate *docstrings*

**Notes**

Note that you should realize that your solution is *synchronous* - you are processing urls sequentially one by one. If performance matters, consider looking into [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/).

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your advice and suggestion. I've already used scrapy to crawl site like this. I wanted to make sure whether I can apply the way I started here if need be. Btw, you once give me a demo on how to use session and in that case request was made once. If i consider this example, it is hard for me to use session cause when multiple requests are concerned then i don't know how to deploy session. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 good. What do you mean by "deploy session"? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir for you concern. I meant, apply or use session in multiple requests. Don't get me wrong for my linguistic difficulty.

Comment: @SMth80 sure, your english is great. In the simplest case, you can pass the `session` instance as an argument to every function and use `session.get()` instead of `requests.get()`. Though, having a class and a `session` class attribute would probably be better in terms of code organization. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir, for your answer. I've got it sorted already. One last thing to ask on this topic: i just found out that the crawler is parsing all the required fields form all pages except the first page cause using xpath, the crawler always locates the href links from the second one. In your spare time you may take a look into it. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @SMth80 please consider posting this as a question with your current code and as maximum details as possible on SO. This way it would be easier to help and more people may potentially help - not just me here in comments. Thank you for understanding!